# Distinction between the universe of a model and the domain of a model?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Distinction between the universe of a model and the domain of a model?

I'm pretty sure I'm wrong about this.  But even reading Wiki, I'm still not clear.

I'll use an example to illustrate what I take to be the distinction:

It seems to me a model can have a finite domain but an uncountable universe: {R}.  The domain has 1 element, while the universe has uncountably many elements.

**EDIT**: Isn't there another difference?  For example, we might say that in order for M to be a countable model of ZFC there must be *universe*, *V* (otherwise from what perspective could we say that M was countable?).  Here, domain and universe are different.  Furthermore, is *V* a proper class (the class of all sets?).

Comment: I cannot see any difference. Usually call it the underlying set.  More often, (wrongly) don't bother to make a notational distinction between a model and its underlying set, letting context determine intended meaning.

Comment: As far as I know, the universe of a model and the domain of a model are exactly the same thing. I double checked in Wilfrid Hodges' 'A Shorter Model Theory' to confirm this.

Comment: @student555: So that the question will not remain unanswered, could you write a brief answer? Clearly it can be very short.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Is the answer simply, "universe" and "domain" are the same; they both refer to the underlying set of the model.

Comment: @picheal: Yes. By the way, Wikipedia is good for quick overviews, but the words don't always bear close scrutiny, and for detail one should go to less anonymous sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Universe and domain are the same; they both refer to the underlying set of the model.